# Json schema requiring node in wrong level

Tags: java, json, jsonschema

I'm trying to create a json schema in the following way:

```
 {
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/schema#",
  "title": "Layout",
  "description": "The layout created by the user",
  "type": "object",
  "definitions": {
    "stdAttribute": {
      "type": "object",
      "properties": {
        "attributeValue": {
          "type": "object"
        },
        "attributeName": {
          "type": "string"
        }
      }
    },
    "stdItem": {
      "type": "object",
      "required" : ["stdAttributes"],
      "properties": {
        "stdType": {
          "enum": [
            "CONTAINER",
            "TEXT",
            "TEXTAREA",
            "BUTTON",
            "LABEL",
            "IMAGE",
            "MARCIMAGE",
            "DATA",
            "SELECT",
            "TABLE"
          ]
        },
        "stdAttributes": {
          "type": "array",
          "items": {
            "$ref": "#/definitions/stdAttribute"
          }
        },
        "children": {
          "type": "array",
          "items": {
            "$ref": "#/definitions/stdItem"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "properties": {
    "layoutItem": {
      "$ref": "#/definitions/stdItem"
    }
  }
}
```

I'm validating the following json against it:

```
{
  "layoutItem": {
    "stdItem": {
      "stdType": "CONTAINER",
      "stdAttributes": [],
      "children": []
    }
  }
}
```

The problem is that when i'm running the java validator i get an error because i specify the "**stdAtrributes**" node as required by "**stdItem**" and the validator can't fint it.

I tried to define the required array inside the properties but the schema gets invalidated.

If i put "**stdAttributes**" outside "**stdItem**", it works.

Does anyone know how can i define this requiment for "**stdItem**"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem in your schema is that you want the value of `layoutItem` to be valid according to the schema at `#/definitions/stdItem`.

But this schema does not define an object with a `stdItem` property as you want (looking at your data), it defines an object with properties `stdType`, `stdAttributes` and `children` and requires that the property `stdAttributes` is present. In other words, it is a schema for the following data:

```
{
  "layoutItem": {
    "stdType": "CONTAINER",
    "stdAttributes": [],
    "children": []
  }
}
```

For your data the schema should be:

```
 {
  ...
  "definitions": {
    ...
    "stdItem": {
      "type": "object",
      "required" : ["stdItem"],
      "properties": {
        "stdItem": {
          "type": "object",
          "required" : ["stdAttributes"],
          "properties": {
            "stdType": { ... },
            "stdAttributes": { ... },
            "children": { ... }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  ...
}
```